# How to add an ipvlan (l3) to pihole's yaml manifest?

Tags: docker, yaml, containers, pihole

I hope all of you are doing fine! I have a litle problem with "yaml"file. How can I add my ipvlan (l3= layer3) to pihole's yml manifest?

I did this but it didn't work

`networks: ipvlan_network: external: name: my-ipvlan-l3`